# Assign the equivalent of one cpu core to a process - relative and not exclusive

Tags: linux

I have an idea about `taskset` and `isolcpu` on `linux`.

However what I need is to have a process run on equivalent power of 1 (or X) cpu cores but not have to have any affinity to any 1 cpu core. It should be able to be scheduled on any of the cores and move around as long as it does not go beyond the equivalent rating of a single core.

For eg: running `top` I see (on a 4 core box) cpu going up to 400%. I want that process to max out at 100% cpu (1 core) but it could be scheduled on any of the cores and move around. No cpu affinity.

Hope it makes sense. Please let me know of any questions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cgroups+limit+cpu

Comment: Thanks. If you could ask this as an answer!